# finding the limit of $a_n=\sqrt[3]{n}\cdot\frac{\sin n}{\sqrt{n+1}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I need to find the limit of $$a_n=\sqrt[3]{n}\cdot\frac{\sin( n)}{\sqrt{n+1}}$$

But $\sin(n)$ does not have a limit as it tends to infinity. What is the trick here?

Comment: You can use continuity of functions, right?

Comment: @k.stm Sorry but where is continuity, of which function, involved here?

Comment: @Did You can involve it by viewing $\lvert a_n \rvert$ as the image of $\lvert a_n \rvert^6$ under the continuous function $[0..∞) → [0..∞),~x ↦ \sqrt[6]{x}$. I suspected that the questioner was distracted by the roots to not see that
$$\tfrac{\sqrt[3] n}{\sqrt{n+1}} \overset{n → ∞}\longrightarrow 0,$$
so $\sin n$ doesn’t matter.

Comment: @k.stm And the **continuity** is relevant because?

Comment: @Did The continuty at zero implies that null sequences are taken to null sequences.

Comment: @k.stm Sorry but this seems an awfully intricate way of saying that $1/n^{1/6}\to0$. Sure that sending the OP to these considerations is optimal to make them solve the exercise?

Comment: @Did No, I think it depends on the level of the questioner. And that’s also part of why I didn’t answer. But I firmly believe that “I can pretend that the term I’m looking at is a continuous transformation of some simpler, nicer term where I can *see* what’s going on” is a powerful realisation, so that’s why I was considering going that way.

Comment: @k.stm Precisely, given what one can suspect the OP's maturity is, you are almost certain to send them into the wall when invoking continuity.

Comment: @Did In particular, students which have started some analysis course by working out limits by hand and ended up with the abstractions of continuity and so on, can apply these abstractions by revising the limits they have calculated and rework them with the new tools. But yeah, I get the objections. As I said: It’s part of why I didn’t answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the squeeze theorem:

$$0 \le \frac{\sqrt[3]{n} \cdot\left|\sin n\right|}{\sqrt{n+1}} \le \frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt[6]{n}}}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}} \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} 0$$

Hence, $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sqrt[3]{n} \sin n}{\sqrt{n+1}} = 0$.

Comment: I understand how you find $$\sqrt[3]{n}\cdot\frac{\sin n}{\sqrt{n+1}}<\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt[6]{n}}}{\sqrt{n}}$$ I dont see how this leads you to $$\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt[6]{n}}}{\sqrt{n+\frac{1}{n}}}$$ the first term also serves my purpose, if I know the epsilon and have to solve for $n$

Comment: @PhilippWulff First bound $\left|\sin n\right| \le 1$ and then multiply both the numerator and the denominator with $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$:
$$\frac{\sqrt[3]{n}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} }{\sqrt{n+1}\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}} =\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt[6]{n}}}{\sqrt{1 + \frac{1}n}}$$
Now you can further bound $1 + \frac{1}{n} \ge 1$ to obtain:
$$\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt[6]{n}}}{\sqrt{1 + \frac{1}n}} \le \frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt[6]{n}}}{\sqrt{n}} = \frac{1}{n^{\frac23}}$$
You can find $n$ given $\varepsilon$ from here.

Comment: Thanks. That clarifies it.

Answer (score 1):

**HINTS:**

$$|\sin(n)|\le 1$$

and

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n^{1/3}}{\sqrt{n+1}}=0$$